# Unable to resolve the users in people picker. SharePoint Foundation 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, claim-provider

From certain domains, users are not resolving in our SharePoint environment.

event viewer logs:

```
An exception occurred in AD claim provider when calling SPClaimProvider.FillResolve(): Error during decryption. System error code 0
```

When i gone through the ULS Logs,

> GetUserInfoFromMembershipProvider: Exception in
>   SPUtility.ResolvePrincipal. WebApp:
>   '67f5b370-a9af-4ea6-8efe-7ff42f33bff1', LoginName:
>   'i:0#.w|DomainName\User', bIsRole: 'False', Exception:
>   'System.ArgumentException: Error during decryption. System error code
>   0.      at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPCredentialManager.DecryptWithApplicationCredentialKey(Byte[]
>   rgbEncryptedPassphrase)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPPeoplePickerSearchActiveDirectoryDomain.get_Password()
>   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPActiveDirectoryDomain..ctor(SPPeoplePickerSearchActiveDirectoryDomain
>   peoplePickerDomain)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUserUtility.GetWindowsPrincipalResolvers(SPWebApplication
>   webApp, Boolean includeUpnInOperations, String
>   userAccountDirectoryPathRestriction, SPPrincipalResolver
>   bySidResolver)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUserUtility.CreatePrincipalResolvers(SPWebApplication
>   webApp, ICollection`1 urlZones, Nullable`1 currentZone,
>   SPPrincipalResolver bySidResolver, String
>   userAccountDirectoryPathRestriction, Boolean alwaysAddWindowsResolver,
>   Boolean includeUpnInOperations)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtility.ResolveWindowsPrincipal(SPWeb
>   web, SPWebApplication webApp, String input, SPPrincipalType scopes,
>   Boolean inputIsEmailOnly, Boolean includeUpnInOperations)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.Claims.SPActiveDirectoryClaimProvider.ResolvePrincipalInfo(Uri
>   context, SPPrincipalType principalType, Boolean inputIsEmailOnly,
>   Boolean disableEmailResolve, Boolean resolveIncludesUpnProperty,
>   String resolveInput, Boolean& resolved)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.Claims.SPActiveDirectoryClaimProvider.FillResolve(Uri
>   context, String[] entityTypes, Boolean inputIsEmailOnly, String
>   resolveInput, List`1 resolved)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.Claims.SPActiveDirectoryClaimProvider.FillResolve(Uri
>   context, String[] entityTypes, SPClaim resolveInput, List`1 resolved) 
>   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.Claims.SPClaimProvider.Resolve(Uri
>   context, String[] entityTypes, SPClaim resolveInput)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.Claims.SPClaimProviderOperations.Resolve(Uri
>   context, SPClaimProviderOperationOptions mode, String[] providerNames,
>   String[] entityTypes, SPClaim resolveInput)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtility.ResolvePrincipalClaims(SPWeb
>   web, SPWebApplication webApplication, Nullable`1 urlZone, String
>   input, SPPrincipalType scopes, SPPrincipalSource sources,
>   SPPrincipalInfo user, Boolean inputIsEmailOnly)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtility.ResolvePrincipalInternal(SPWeb
>   web, SPWebApplication webApp, Nullable`1 urlZone, String input,
>   SPPrincipalType scopes, SPPrincipalSource sources, SPUserCollection
>   usersContainer, Boolean inputIsEmailOnly, Boolean
>   alwaysAddWindowsResolver)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtility.ResolvePrincipal(SPWebApplication
>   webApp, Nullable`1 urlZone, String input, SPPrincipalType scopes,
>   SPPrincipalSource sources, Boolean inputIsEmailOnly)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPManagedCodeInterop.GetUserInfoFromMembershipProvider(Guid
>   siteId, String loginName, Boolean bIsRole, Boolean& userExists,
>   String& email, String& title, String& userKey, String& mobilePhone,
>   Boolean& isShareByEmailGuestUser)'.

Answer (score 1):

Unless these domains are one-way trusts, you can remove the username and password from the `PeoplePickerSettings` for that particular domain.

With that said, you must set the application credential key on each server in the farm to the same value. The `stsadm` command for setting the `setapppassword` parameter only sets the value on that particular server.

Lastly, verify on the registry key `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Shared Tools\Web Server Extensions\15.0\Secure` that `WSS_WPG` has Read rights and `WSS_ADMIN_WPG` has Full Control on each SharePoint server.

Comment: These are one way trust domains, can i still remove the username and password?

Comment: No, if you have a one-way trust you need the username and password. At this point, it just sounds like you need to set the app cred key on each farm member (I do not recall if you need to reset your `PeoplePickerSettings` after doing so -- I'd assume so since you're establishing a new encryption key).

Comment: Ok, can you kindly share any articles to understand the literature behind and sequence of commands to be executed?

Comment: 1) 
$wa = Get-SPWebApplication http://spwebapp1
$wa.PeoplePickerSettings.ActiveDirectoryCustomFilter = $null
$wa.Update()

2)
stsadm.exe -o setapppassword -password pwd12345

3)
stsadm -o setproperty -pn peoplepicker-searchadcustomfilter -pv "domain:adforest" -url "https://constso.com" 

4)
IISRESET

Will the above sequence of steps work?

Comment: i performed it, but the issue still exists. Post executing those commands, i did IIS reset, config cache clear and rebooted my server. Wondering is there any possibility that the old password is cache some where? Interestingly post executing those commands, i am not seeing any errors in my event viewer or ULS logs, but user is still not resolving.

Answer (score 0):

I will leave this here as it took me some time to verify what was wrong.

I have a people picker that should take users from 2 domain. Followed all the steps from great [article](https://thesharepointfarm.com/2014/01/powershell-for-people-picker-properties/).

I've tried already all the troubleshooting from [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/32467.sharepoint-2013-troubleshooting-sorry-were-having-trouble-reaching-the-server.aspx) without success.

Still error `Sorry, we’re having trouble reaching the server`.

What I found that before you setup the `PeoplePickerSettings.SearchActiveDirectoryDomains` you have to run the [command](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/sharepoint/troubleshoot/people-picker/stops-resolving-other-domain-users):

```
STSADM.exe -o setapppassword -password key
```

And then also Alberto [suggested](https://albandrodsmemory.com/2015/12/15/sharepoint-in-trusted-domains/) adding to `PeoplePickerSettings.SearchActiveDirectoryDomains` should be run on each server on the farm!

Finally all works as expected